# When I enable Wifi Direct, why the wifi will disabled?

Tags: android, sony, wifi-direct

My device is Sony Ericsson Arc S.

Android: 4.0.4

I root my cellphone and add '**android.hardware.wifi.direct.xml**' in **/system/etc/permissions/**.

I can see wifi direct option in my Settings.

When I enable wifi direct, it show the wifi direct is opened, but my wifi is disable.

And then I enable wifi, my wifi direct change to disable.

Anybody know how can let my cellphone support wifi direct?

or it's impossible? Why?

Thanks~

Comment: this question is not about development. It should be moved here :
http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well with Wifi Direct one of the device acts like a wifi access point, so your phone is connecting to this wifi network if you use wifi direct, so you can't connect to another wifi signal, that's why you can't enable wifi and wifi direct at the same time.

Comment: Because I run WiFiDirectDemo is failed. When run discoverPeers, it show 'Discovery Failed : reason Code is 0'. I don't know what happened!

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi direct stack in ICS makes you turn off WiFi in order to use WiFi direct. They cannot be run simultaneously. In Android 4.1, they changed it, where it 'always' running while WiFi is on, however I have found that it often does not respond to discovery requests unless you open the WiFi direct menu within a certain timeframe from when the other device does a search.

I don't have a source for you unfortunately, but I remember reading it somewhere. It acts this way (and explains it) on my LG Mach 4.0.4.